# Different results for inverse of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, inverse

I have a 5 by 5 matrix:

```
t <- read.table(header=FALSE, 
text=" 1    0   0   -0.0000009038   0
0   1   0   0.0000000000    0
0   0   1   0.0000000000    0
0   0   0   1.0000000000    0
0   0   0   0.0000000000    1
")
```

When I try to take the inverse of this matrix, I get different results with

```
tt <- solve(t)
```

and

```
tt <- 1/(t)
```

Why? Shouldn't they both work?

Comment: 1/t is not the inverse of a matrix. it is rather elementwise reciprocal. same way in math if you have a function, f(x), then 1/f(x) is not the inverse of the matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/t is not the inverse of a matrix. It is rather elementwise reciprocal. Same way in math if you have a function, f(x), then 1/f(x) is not the inverse of the matrix.

Note that even in math, the inverse of a matrix is never written as `1/A` if A is a matrix.

In R. The inverse of a matrix is computed as `solve(A)`

Comment: Ah thanks. But I have another 5 by 5 matrix: ```785434 0 0 0 0
0 894783 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 16595944 0
0 0 0 0 0```where solve(A) does not work. It says this matrix is singular, but how can it be if the matrix above worked fine? Don't they have the same properties?

Comment: @JohannaH no they dont have the same property. You cannot find an incerse of a singular matrix. Ie if the determinant of a matrix is 0, or simply put if any of the eigen values of a matrix is zero, then the matrix is singular hence you cannot find uts inverse. Please look on google how to find inverse of a 2×2 matrix for example